# Why $request got nothing but $request->something is available?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel - 5.7.*
PHP - 7.1.3

Why does `json_encode($request)` give me this response:

```
{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}
```

But when I `$request->id` <<< (What I pass in), I'm able to get the ID.

Why won't it show the ID in the `$request` when I print it out?

Comment: `\Iluminate\Http\Request` is a collection of ParameterBag, HeaderBag, etc... `$request->all()` is what you are looking for i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```php
$request->all()
```

to get whatever has been sent to controller.

You can read about this in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input)